# Contact form with Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, contact-form

Attempting to set up a Jquery and PHP Contact form on my website found here http://www.greenlite.co.uk/Contactus.html

I think I'm doing something wrong with the PHP file. I've put the necessary email into the PHP file but I'm not sure if I've linked it in the main code correctly, or even how to do that. Or even where to add it on the root file.

Here's the code I'm using;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Form</title>

    <link href="js/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="wrap">
  <h1>Contact Greenlite Controls</h1>
  <form id="contactform" action="processForm.php" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label for="message">Message:</label></td>
        <td><textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Send" id="send" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <div id="response"></div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the PHP

```
<?php

// Clean up the input values
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
 if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
$_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

  $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}

// Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

// Test input values for errors
$errors = array();
if(strlen($name) < 2) {
  if(!$name) {
    $errors[] = "You must enter a name.";
  } else {
    $errors[] = "Name must be at least 2 characters.";
  }
}
 if(!$email) {
  $errors[] = "You must enter an email.";
} else if(!validEmail($email)) {
  $errors[] = "You must enter a valid email.";
}
if(strlen($message) < 10) {
  if(!$message) {
    $errors[] = "You must enter a message.";
  } else {
    $errors[] = "Message must be at least 10 characters.";
  }
}

if($errors) {
  // Output errors and die with a failure message
   $errortext = "";
  foreach($errors as $error) {
    $errortext .= "<li>".$error."</li>";
  }
  die("<span class='failure'>The following errors occured:<ul>". $errortext ."</ul>        </span>");
}

// Send the email
$to = "mick@greenlite.co.uk";
$subject = "Contact Form: $name";
$message = "$message";
$headers = "From: $email";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Die with a success message
die("<span class='success'>Success! Your message has been sent.</span>");

// A function that checks to see if
// an email is valid
function validEmail($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
  }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
     {
       // local part starts or ends with '.'
     $isValid = false;
  }
  else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
  {
     // local part has two consecutive dots
     $isValid = false;
  }
  else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
  {
     // character not valid in domain part
     $isValid = false;
  }
  else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
  {
     // domain part has two consecutive dots
     $isValid = false;
  }
  else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
  {
     // character not valid in local part unless
     // local part is quoted
     if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
         str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
     {
        $isValid = false;
     }
  }
  if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
  {
     // domain not found in DNS
     $isValid = false;
    }
   }
        return $isValid;
    }

    ?>
```

Basically if it's not clear, after I use the contact form I get "Sending" but it does not die. I don't get a Success message and the mail doesn't send. I can only assume it's something to do with the PHP.

I've put the PHP file into a folder on the root called php and tried to call it from "action="php/ProcessForm.php" but this didn't make a difference.

Comment: is `sendmail` properly set?

Comment: I think it might be my link to the PHP file on action="ProcessForm.php" testing it now

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do not validate the form with Jquery, instead inside the PHP??

Try to use AJAX to send your form and Jquery UI to response your user with the sucess or failure.

Try to use the .serialize() (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function in query and $.ajax.

This way, you'll can clean up your php file and find the error.

Look a simple example of the code:

Call the submit funcion:

```
  $().ready(function(e) {
    $("#cad_cliente").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        insertDataForm(getDataForm());
                });
        return false;
    });
```

Serialize the parameters:

```
  function getDataForm(){
    var params=$("#cad_cliente").serialize();
    return params;
  }
```

Post the values in your php file:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url:'registra.php',
        data:params,
        cache:false,
        success: function(){
            Alert("mesenge");
        }
    });
}
```

Glad if i could help you...

Comment: I figured if a user doesn’t have javascript enabled when they submit the form no errors will occur?

Comment: You should always validate input on the server side (PHP), regardless of whether you validate it with JQuery/JavaScript before hand. Remember that.

Comment: jQuery validation is an addition to server side validation - which is **mandatory**. While client side validation (javascript) is optional, and done more to be user friendly.

Comment: Right. Sorry completely new to this, just making a site for my company. Trying to understand the answer from mpleandro. Do I put the Seralize paramaters before or after the submit function

Comment: If you see on http://www.greenlite.co.uk/Contactus.html I just get stuck with "Sending"

Comment: The Serialize() parameter is to get the values of your form. You put before the function. The $.ajax is to post your values in the PHP file.